# Merge If statements into Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the original code to some new lines of code

so If c = certain text, also if the height is between certain number, a value gets assigned. But when I run the new code, VBA gives me an error: Object Variable not set...Help!

See below for the original code, which works fine
original code:

```
Sub TheMiddleMan()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Range, rng As Range, x As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    If c = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    c = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    c = "C COLLAR (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    c = "D BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    c = "SAN MH(5""" & " WALL)" Or _
    c = "MH 72""" & " DIA(8""" & " WALL)" Then
    c = c & " " & c.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next c
For Each c In rng
    x = Val(c)
    Select Case x
        Case 12 To 19
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22122J"
        Case 20 To 32
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22123J"
        Case 33 To 42
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22124J"
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

And below is the new code
New code:

```
Sub TheMiddleMan()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Range, rng As Range, x As Long, d As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C COLLAR (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "D BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "SAN MH(5""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "MH 72""" & " DIA(8""" & " WALL)" Then
    d = d & " " & d.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next
For Each c In rng
For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    x = Val(c)
    Select Case x
        Case 12 To 19
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22122J"
            End If
            If d = "C Base (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
        Case 20 To 32
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21122J"
            End If
            If d = "C Base (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
        Case 33 To 42
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            d.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21122J"
            End If
            If d = "C Base (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            d.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
    End Select
Next
Next
```

End Sub

codes for updating column D (this is working just fine by itself):

```
Sub ZackCase()
Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, rng As Range, x As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))

For Each c In rng
    x = Val(c)
    Select Case x
        Case 12 To 19
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22122J"
        Case 20 To 32
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22123J"
        Case 33 To 42
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22124J"
    End Select
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Oh you aren't missing a `Then`, it's near the end. You can't nest a `Select Case` inside an `If... Then`. Maybe the lines `c = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Or _` and `c = "MH 72""" & " DIA(8""" & " WALL)" Then` are in the wrong spot?

Comment: @BigBen so Select Case cannot be nested in if statements, but can I nest If....then inside of Select Case?

Comment: Yes, inside a `Case` (i.e. under a `Case` line), you can use `If...Then`.

Comment: Okay, I updated it. Now the error is variable d is not defined... @BigBen

Comment: The code for each case looks the same is that correct ?

Comment: On your original code, I don't see what that first `For Each c In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)` loop is doing.  I'm testing it here and realizing it only cares about the second loop.  Am I wrong?

Comment: They are supposed to be different item codes, but since I am just testing out the VBA, I didnt bother to change them yet @CDP1802

Comment: No, my bad.  It should concatenate the measurement (?) from column L into the existing column K.  I made an error transcribing your strings (btw -- I think you could write those without the `&` operator).

Comment: New code updated, so they first block of If statements are just like you said, pull value from L to K (at the end of the text). However, the second block of Select Case with If statements, They are supposed to change the value in column D based on the 2 factors ( case range and the texts like C Box in the If statements), this isnt working... @wackojacko1997

Comment: `d = d & " " & c.Offset(, 1)` appears to add something to the value but you are testing in the case later without any addition ?

Comment: @CDP1802 the line you are referring to simply pull the value from L, and adding it to the end of the text string in K       K: D Box (6"wall) L:14", after running this macro K becomes: D Box(6" wall) 14"

Comment: Yes but in the second loop you have `If d = "D BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then` which won't be true.

Comment: @CDP1802 I see what you mean, how would you recommend to fix this? change the d in the second loop to another variable name?

Comment: One additional comment @BigBen:  It wasn't clear to me in your first comment where Zac was mixing `Select Case` and `If` statement.  You can have either one inside the other so long as they are completely contained, right? (i.e. nest `Select Case; End Select` within an `If Then; End If` and vice versa)  I feel that Zac's response and your confirmation are misleading/ talking past each other.

Comment: Do you intend expanding the list of items or the range of numbers in case statements ?

Comment: @wackojacko1997 the problem was that the `Select Case` was after the `If` but before the `Then`. As you describe it though, no problem at all.

Comment: It is good to know that Select Case can be nested inside the If statements. I see you updated your answer, can’t wait to try it out as soon as I get home . @wackojacko1997

Comment: Yeah I will expand this list a lot, it will contain well over a hundred item codes @CDP1802

Comment: If you're going to do "well over a hundred item codes", you might want to look at a different strategy than using a `Select Case` statement.  It should be a different discussion/question, but what we did in this question doesn't really scale well if you're just trying to do essentially a table lookup.

Comment: Okay, I will need to explore some other options then. If you dont mind, can you point me in the general direction? How would you approach this if you have to deal with 100-400 of these items.. @wackojacko1997

Comment: As a starting point, I would consider using a reference worksheet (could be another workbook) that has two columns (like you would do a `=VLOOKUP()`, but I would use VBA `Range.Find()` to lookup the initial value (e.g. Column A), and then once found, `Range.Offset(0,1)` to get Column B's value to then place wherever you need it.  There's probably better ways than that, but it's a starting point.

Comment: The nice thing about putting the values in a lookup table is that you can easily to a mass change/update without modifying your code if you set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## One possible answer...

Try this:

```
Sub TheMiddleMan2()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Range, rng As Range, x As Long, d As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row


For Each c In rng
For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    x = Val(c)
    Select Case x
        Case 12 To 19
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F22122J"
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
        Case 20 To 32
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21122J"
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
        Case 33 To 42
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21122J"
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = "F21123J"
            End If
    End Select
Next
Next

For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    Debug.Print d
    Debug.Print "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)"
    If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C COLLAR (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "D BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "SAN MH(5""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "MH 72""" & " DIA(8""" & " WALL)" Then
    d = d & " " & d.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

### Changes I made:

1. There was inconsistency in the string where you use "BASE" vs. "Base", and changed that.
2. I flipped the order of the two primary loops because if you did them in the orignal order, you change column K before you can do the test within you `Select Case` statement.
3. The line `d = d & " " & c.Offset(, 1)` should be `d = d & " " & d.Offset(, 1)` (did you just update this?  I don't see it now, but I swear I was getting this as the object var not set problem).

Anyway, it seems to work on my end as I understand your request.

---

## Updated Answer

```
Sub TheMiddleMan2()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Range, rng As Range, x As Long, d As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
'-------------------------------------
' Removed the previous c loop
'-------------------------------------
For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    x = Val(d.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    Set c = d.Offset(0, -7)  ' For ease of use and updating, I set c to be the cell in Column D.  I know, it's a bad naming convention.
    Select Case x
        Case 12 To 19
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BOX 12 to 19"      ' I set all the values to be explicit so I know where in the Case Statement the end result came from.
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BASE 12 to 19"
            End If
        Case 20 To 32
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BOX 20 to 32"
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BASE 20 to 32"
            End If
        Case 33 To 42
            If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BOX 33 to 42"
            End If
            If d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Then
            c.Value = "BASE 33 to 42"
            End If
    End Select
Next

For Each d In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
    Debug.Print d
    Debug.Print "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)"
    If d = "C BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C BASE (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "C COLLAR (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "D BOX (6""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "SAN MH(5""" & " WALL)" Or _
    d = "MH 72""" & " DIA(8""" & " WALL)" Then
    d = d & " " & d.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

And here's what it looks like on my end:
[image]

Comment: Good catch on the order of the primary loops ! and yes I saw that c in there so I changed it to d...However, your code is having the same issue as mine though. Your first block of code is supposed to update column D in the excel, and it is doing nothing at the moment.

Comment: Meh.  This is still not quite right.  The double loop: `For Each c In rng` and `For Each d in ws.Range(...`  I think this is causing the overwrite of the F21122J value with the F21123J.

Comment: I will update the question and post a working block of codes by itself, so you know exactly what I mean by updating column D.

Comment: yeah I am trying to troubleshoot this block myself, being a newbie I cant really pinpoint the issue. No error message at all, but the column is not updating

Comment: It is actually updating when I run it, but then it gets overwritten because you have these double loops.  You see it when stepping through the code.   You also have an issue where your new code's `Case 33 to 42` doesn't use the F22124J code?  As I compare original to new code, they don't actually work the same?  Is the original code absolutely correct and doing what you want?

Comment: I am not worried about the F22124J part, this number can be anything. the reason I am modifying the original code is because the second block of codes in the original code only updates item# based on the height value, which is in column L. I need this block to update item# based on two values: value in L, and the text in k. I was hoping to achieve that by adding the If statements into the Select Case statements..

Comment: Your code seems to be working great now, wow, thanks man ! @wackojacko1997

Comment: Cool.  When you're fully satisfied that it's everything you hoped for, please mark it as the accepted answer so long as it meets your need on this question.

Comment: yep, already marked it as accepted answer. I really appreciate your help on this !

Answer (score 0):

Use another sheet to configure the codes for each item
[image]

and use Match for find them

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub TheMiddleMan()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsConfig As Worksheet
    Dim k As Range, ar, s As String, h As String
    Dim x As Single, lr As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, bHasL As Boolean
    Dim rngItems As Range, v As Variant
    
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    Set wsConfig = Sheets(2)
    With wsConfig
         lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         Set rngItems = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    End With
    'MsgBox lr - 1 & " items found"
    
    With ws
        lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each k In .Range("K2:K" & lr)
        
            s = Trim(k.Value2)
            h = k.Offset(, 1) ' col L height
            x = Val(h) ' remove "
            
            ' has item got height, romove for match
            If Right(s, Len(h) + 1) = " " & h Then
                s = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(h) - 1)
                bHasL = True
            Else
                bHasL = False
            End If
            
            ' match
            v = Application.Match(s, rngItems, 0)
            If Not IsError(v) Then
           
                ' select column according to quantity
                Select Case Val(x)
                    Case 12 To 19: c = 2
                    Case 20 To 32: c = 3
                    Case 33 To 42: c = 4
                    Case Else: c = 0
                End Select
            
                If c > 0 Then
                    ' get code from config
                    k.Offset(, -7) = wsConfig.Cells(v, c)
                End If
                
                ' add col L if not already
                If bHasL = False Then
                     k.Value2 = k.Value2 & " " & h
                End If
            
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows matched", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```